# how can i add multiple images in article detail page in DNNGO xBlog?

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I have added the DNNGO xBlog module in DNN. but it only allow me to add just one pic in article detail page for pop up. 
I want to add multiple images in article detail page for popup.

Need help about it to how to do it ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Using DNN, if the module is using the HTML editor, you can insert images using the image viewer built into the rich text editor.

Other than that, you'll need to contact the vendor of the module and see what they support.

Comment: i don't want to add images in HTML editor. i am talking about this module 
http://www.dnngo.net/OurModules/xNews/Newsdetail.aspx
it doesn't allow to upload multiple images in one article detail for pop up. someone told me it can be enable from customizing the module. 
but how???

Answer (score 0):

Like @ChrisHammond says, this is just an HTML editor, so should be able to insert images via the Rich Editor or copy/paste HTML code.

But, for further customization:

If you go into the Admin options, then choose the Template tab, there is a Detail Template section.  Here, you can customize your Detail template.

Comment: i don't want to add images in HTML editor. i am talking about this module dnngo.net/OurModules/xNews/Newsdetail.aspx it doesn't allow to upload multiple images in one article detail for pop up. someone told me it can be enable from customizing the module. but how???

Comment: Sorry, but I'm using their older News module and this must be something new. Make sure you are on the latest version. I had an issue once, and then they had me upgrade.  The upgrade fixed my problem. Other than that, I'd put in a support ticket.